# How to check draw letter is alphabet

Tags: ios, iphone, core-graphics

If I draw any characters on screen with touch then how can I detect the drawn texture is between A to Z ? How can I match it with alphabets ?

And correct format.

Comment: What was the question? Could you clarify?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check draw alphabets is from A-Z or current](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990774/how-to-check-draw-alphabets-is-from-a-z-or-current)

Comment: I want to check the draw text shape is an alphabet or not. If yes then which alphabets

Comment: have you check links I mentioned ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think below links can be useful to accomplish your approach.

Links :

(1) [drawing on iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352822/drawing-on-iphone)

(2) [How to detect iPhone movement in space using accelerometer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674717/how-to-detect-iphone-movement-in-space-using-accelerometer)

Comment: Doesn't answer the question a bit.